# ui dialog is not opening in ie8 in one pages

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using ui dialog jQUERY but it is not opening in faq link. I am using same dialog box everywhere but it is working all the place in all browser but not working in one page in ie8 and ie9.

### jQuery

```
$( "#dialog" ).dialog
({
    resizable: false,
    height:128,
    modal: true,
    position:['center',150],
    open: function(event, ui) 
    {
        $('#dialog').load
        (
            rootPath+'illinoi_plan_prices/faq_pop_up/'+zipcode+"", 
            function () 
            {
                setTimeout(function() { $("#dialog").dialog("open"); },100);
            }
        );
    },
    close: function() 
    {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});
```

### HTML

```
<div id="dialog" title="Please Select Commodity" style="display: none;"></div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/illinois/css/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've reworked your jQuery a little bit.  What this does is try to load the div with the html prior to creating and opening the dialog.  If that status that is returned is an error, it will open the dialog with the error message telling you why it couldn't load.  Otherwise, your contents should be there, as expected.

```
var $dialog = $("#dialog"),
    rootPath = "http://somesite.com/",  // for demo purposes
    zipcode = "12345";                  // for demo purposes

$dialog.load
(
    rootPath + "illinoi_plan_prices/faq_pop_up/" + zipcode,
    function(response, status, xhr)
    {
        if (status == "error")
        {
            $dialog.append
            (
                "<div style=\"color: red;\">" + 
                    "<p style=\"font-weight: bold;\">" +
                        "<strong>Could not load page:</strong>" +
                    "</p>" +
                    "<p>" + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText + "</p>" +
                "</div>"
            );
        }
        
        $dialog.dialog
        ({
            close: function () { allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error"); },
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            position:['center','center'],
            resizable: false,
            width: 400
        });
    }
);
```

*I've left `illinoi_plan_prices` as it is in your URL, even though `illinois` is the correct spelling.*

### [See jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AXcZ7/)

Comment: if its spelling mistake then how come it works in all other browser.

Comment: Anyone can help I need answer.
and I am using below lib too.
jquery-1.8.2.js